# Question on predefined meanings for operators

Tags: c++

In "The C++ programming language", at page 265, the author makes the following statement:

> Because of historical accident, the operators = (assignment), & (address-of), and , (sequencing;
>   §6.2.2) have predefined meanings when applied to class objects. These predefined meanings can
>   be made inaccessible to general users by making them private:

Then the following example is given:

```
class X {
private:
 void operator=(const X&);
 void operator&();
 void operator,(const X&);
 // ...
};

void f(X a, X b)
{
   a = b;  // error: operator= private
   &a;     // error: operator& private
   a,b;    // error: operator, private
}
```

I can't quite understand what do these "error" comments refer to? Does that mean I should not define a function like `f`, or that all of the `=`, `&`, and `,` operators should be used according to the default way, and it is not necessary to redefine them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This example simply shows a way to prevent yourself or other developers of the code from using operators, which can be used without having been defined in the class, because they're automatically generated (and have default meanings for the operations they represent).

The author of the example meant, that if you try to assign `b` to `a` (in line `a = b`) it will cause an error, because the assignment operator is private in the class definition.

Similar error occurs in case of address-of in the second line, and the comma operator in the third.

Making default operators/constructors private if you know they're not supposed to be used (or haven't been implemented yet) is good, because one may accidentally use a very frequent operator like assignment or copy-constructor, being unaware that it's default behavior conflicts with the class lifecycle. If such operator or constructor is made private at the very beginning of class design, the compiler will generate a compile-time error instead of performing a potentially dangerous operation without notice if the programmer accidentally uses the method.

Think default assignment operator and member pointer: it will copy the pointer whereas you might want the object to be the owner of data. Then, after someone assigns one object to another without knowing that assignment is not implemented, you will end up with a double free error. Instead of that, if the operator is private, you'll get a nice error and the code will not even compile, and you'll know what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

The author intends to point out here that the operators `=`, `&` and `,`  are usually implicitly available for a class.
So if you don't want your objects to be operated on through them then you declare them as `private` thus disallowing their use.

Since they are declared as `private` you cannot access them anymore outside the class and the compiler gives you a compilation error. The function is an example showing that.

Comment: I find this answer clearer than the most upvoted one: the point of *predefined meanings* is that they are present and will work *by default*, and that the only way of *inhibiting* that behavior in C++03 is by declaring them `private` (C++0x adds the `delete` keyword)

Answer (score 1):

Providing your own implementation of any operator is basically the same as implementing a class method. Operators and methods are the same in terms of accessibility. What you do is disallowing access to operators from the caller's code.

It's absolutely the same as if you defined a private method and then tried to call it from some code that is not part of your class. Just make the operators public and errors will go away.

Answer (score 1):

It basically prevents any one from making an 'X' object and using the  "=", "&", and "," operators on that class. Because the author of the class may implement those objects with a meaning that is quite different to what the consumer of the class might think they do ... so its best to prevent them being used at all in the case of ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The function `f` is an example of a user trying to use the private operators. It shows you what code it is that you're preventing by making them private. The comment `// error` means that a program that contained that line would fail to compile for the stated reason.

Answer (score 0):

Before discussing the error, a key here is to understand that these operations will be implicitly made available for your class.  This is the essence of Scott Meyers' advice "Know what functions C++ silently writes and calls."

C++ will automatically implement the assignment operator for your class, but it may not be done correctly (for example, if your class contains a pointer member variable).  By defining the assignment operator explicitly, you are telling the compiler to use your implementation instead of generating one for you.  And by making it private, you are essentially disallowing assignment of one class instance to another.  Anywhere you try to do this in your code, the compiler will complain, which is a good thing if you really don't want assignment to be done.

In function f the author is showing you that these statements will not compile because of how the operators are defined in the class.  It is perfectly acceptable to redefine operators for your class, and sometimes it is definitely required (for example, to implement a deep copy of a pointer member variable in your class).  The point of the example is to show that a) you can provide your own implementation of these operators for your class, and b) because of this you have control over whether the operators are supported and implemented correctly for your class.